# moderation analysis

Tags: regression

I'm using demographic variables (age, number of children, gender, socioeconomic status, educational status) as moderating variables between Self differentiation (independent variable) and Marital Satisfaction (DV). I'm planning to use hierarchical regression is it correct? if in case I would not follow random sampling but instead use purposive sampling would that be possible? should I run tests for normal distribution?

thank you very much for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few questions combined here.

1) Moderation. This is another term for interaction. To test for moderation you can include the interactions of self differentiation with the demographic variables. This presumes you have a large enough sample to avoid overfitting.

2) Hierarchical regression. This depends on what you are trying to find out. One idea is to first include the IV and the moderating variables, but not the interaction, then to include the interactions and see what effects are large and how the addition of the interactions changes things. This is part of the general problem of model selection.

3) Type of sampling. This does not directly affect which type of regression you can or should use; it affects how you can genaralize your results to other populations. Depending on the type of purposive sampling, there may be worked-out methods for dealing with changes. But random sampling is simplest to deal with (not necessarily *best* but simplest).